# Is it possible to create a reusable full subtractor in SystemVerilog?

Tags: digital-logic, system-verilog, computer-arithmetic

I am trying to design a full subtractor in SystemVerilog.

I searched on Wikipedia and I found this https://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=Microprocessor_Design/Add_and_Subtract_Blocks

```
module full_adder(a, b, cin, cout, s);
   input a, b, cin;
   output cout, s;
   wire temp;
   temp = a ^ b;
   s = temp ^ cin;
   cout = (cin & temp) | (a & b);
endmodule
```

But this code seems quite lengthy, and works for only the 1-bit case. I am thinking of taking the 2's complement of the second operand to do subtraction, but that would work only for the 1-bit case. 2's complement is by applying the bitwise negation (`~`) operator and adding `1` to it.

But this won't be reusable since it works only for the 1-bit case. Is there a more reusable approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, but you don't need to.

Just write

```
a - b
```

wherever you would instantiate the full substractor. Your code will be more readable and synthesis hasn't had difficulties with this construct since the 90s.

Answer (score 2):

If you actually want to do addition or subtraction then use the built-in + and - operators, that is what they are there for.

Still if we want to design a multi-bit adder from first principles, we can do it by operating on vectors. So we essentially build a bunch of 1 bit adders in paralell, then wire them up to each other.

```
module full_adder(a, b, cin, cout, s);
   parameter width;
   input [width-1:0] a;
   input [width-1:0] b;
   input cin;

   output cout;
   output [width-1:0] s;   
   wire [width-1:0] temp;
   wire [width-1:0] cininternal;
   wire [width-1:0] coutinternal;
   wire [widht-1:0] sinternal;

   assign cininternal[0] = cin;
   assign cininternal[width-1:1] = coutinternal[widht-2:0];

   assign temp = a ^ b;
   assign s = temp ^ cininternal;
   assign coutinternal = (cininternal & temp) | (a & b); 

   assign cout = coutinternal[width-1];

endmodule
```

To make a subtractor instead of an adder we just invert the second input and invert the carry in and carry out.

```
module full_subtractor(a, b, cin, cout, s);
   parameter width;
   input [width-1:0] a;
   input [width-1:0] b;
   input cin;

   output cout;
   output [width-1:0] s;   
   wire [width-1:0] temp;
   wire [width-1:0] cininternal;
   wire [width-1:0] coutinternal;
   wire [widht-1:0] sinternal;

   assign cininternal[0] = ~cin;
   assign cininternal[width-1:1] = coutinternal[widht-2:0];

   assign temp = a ^ (~b);
   assign s = temp ^ cininternal;
   assign coutinternal = (cininternal & temp) | (a & (~b)); 

   assign cout = ~coutinternal[width-1];

endmodule
```